# Cycling through a list of months with years to check if file exists

Tags: python, date, python-2.7, for-loop, monthcalendar

I am trying to cycle through a list of months with years starting from the year of 2012 and month of November, all the way up to the current year and month.

```
start_year = "2012"
start_month = "November"

month = start_month
year = start_year

# some sort of for loop or cycle here
    try:
        with open('{} {}.csv'.format(month, year)):
           CSVFile = True
        if CSVFile:
            print "do something cool here"
    except IOError:
        CSVFile = False
    print ""
```

Any advice or constructive comments on how to achive this or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks SMNALLY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably do this as follows:

```
import datetime,  os

current_month = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
# this could be more concise if `start_month` were the month number rather than month name
possible_month = datetime.datetime.strptime('%s %s' % (start_month, start_year), '%B %Y').date()
while possible_month <= current_month:
    csv_filename = possible_month.strftime('%B %Y') + '.csv'
    if os.path.exists(csv_filename):
        CSVFile = True
        # do something cool here, and maybe break the loop if you like
    possible_month = (possible_month + datetime.timedelta(days=31)).replace(day=1)
```

Let me know if you need me to expand on how that works.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I loved reading your conversion, had me laughing :P

Comment: @Hyflex: sleep deprived me makes for a very hilarious party guest (nudge nudge wink wink)

Answer (score 4):

```
import datetime as dt
startYear = 2012
startMonth = 11
delta = 1
curr = dt.datetime(year=startYear, month=startMonth, day=1)

now = dt.datetime.now()
endYear = now.year
endMonth = now.month

while dt.datetime(year=year+(delta/12), month=month+(delta%12),day=1) <= now:
    try:
        with open('{} {}.csv'.format(month, year)):
           CSVFile = True
        if CSVFile:
            print "do something cool here"
    except IOError:
        CSVFile = False
    print ""
    delta += 1
```

Comment: Neat redemption, simple, effective and similar to ops post

Comment: Either it's my turn to be overlooking something, or this never actually increments the candidate date.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: You're right. I just fixed it. I should really stop coding without sleep or coffee

Comment: I'm coming to your party

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Go to bed, your code is appreciated but I can see you are suffering from sleep deprivation today. :) Thanks for the solutions guys, will try both and accept the one I find easiest to use.